# SQL Server - insert/select slow after TRUNCATE TABLE has 6 over million rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008, truncate

Seeing slowness in insert/select after truncating a table that has over 6 million rows.

I daily insert 5 to 6 millions records into a table and I was able to insert/select data without any issue for some 7 or 8 days but when the table size went above 10 GB / 30 million rows, there were a few timeout issues.

So I thought of truncating the table daily before data uploading since 1 day's data is enough for me. Now I am seeing extreme slowness in insert/select till i rebuild index in middle of upload. last 2 days it took 5 hours to insert 1 million rows , after a index rebuild remaining 3.5 to 4 million rows went into table in less than 15 mins. I dont prefer to rebuild index in middle of my upload process.

i don't do a .NET Bulk insert , i insert rows in batches using Stored proc , since i do some validation.

I am using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: This problem is most likely not due to the truncation. Does the slowness start immediately after truncation? How long does it last? How do you define "slowness"? How did you measure it?

Comment: it is slow after truncate ,it took nearly 5hours to insert 1 million rows. then after a rebuild index , remaining 4.5 million rows got inserted in less than 15 mins. i don't do a .NET Bulk insert , i insert rows in batches using Stored proc , since i do some validation.

Comment: sorry , slowness last till i rebuild index. Slowness i mean , duration to insert records , normally(for 6 to 7 days) it took less than 5 or 6 seconds to insert a batch 80K rows , but since when i started truncating  it taking minutes for same batch. after i rebuild index every thing were back to normal. i don't prefer to rebuild index in middle of my upload process .

Comment: That information is helpful. An unusual case. No obvious problems.; Do you have auto update statistics enabled? How much memory does the server have? Is the process fast again after updating statistics on that table but without rebuilding the index?

Comment: No ,auto update statistics is not enabled .we have memory nearly 1TB , we using SAN disk .i have not tried update stats, since it is Production DB , waiting on approval. We did not had this issue in testing environment , which has memory of 100GB. Also 5/6 millions rows consume memory of 1.7 to 1.8 GB . Our database growth is 1GB.

Comment: Ah no auto update stats... That probably means your statistics are crazily out of date. Either update them during the import process, or enable auto update stats, or rebuild the index during the import process or use a plan guide to force a sane execution plan (not recommended because it's hard and fragile).

Comment: can you try using dropping the indexes and see the performance and re-create them at the end of 6 million rows inserted???

Comment: thx usr ..  hope auto update stats will resolve this issue , test db  has auto update stats enabled..will update you after enabling it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After enabling auto stats update , every thing went normal. from now After truncating big tables i will makes sure table stats get updated if DB auto stats update is disabled.. thanks every one for all your valuable suggestions.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you update your statistics on all your indexes... and it probably wouldn't hurt to shrink your log file.  There are articles on how to do both all over the internet.  But that's my best guess at what's going on.

Comment: This does not address the specific problem. This is very general advice. I doubt that it applies

Comment: Actually, bad optimizer estimates for plans can cause serious performance issues.  It's certainly something that should be done or at least looked at... given the lack of information in the original question to go on.

Comment: I will add a note that the selected answer is exactly the answer I gave, so the two down-votes are definitely not warranted.

Comment: When you gave this answer there was no clue statistics would be the problem. Now that we know they are the problem you'd need to say that auto update stats was the problem, not just stats in general. Furthermore, shrinking the log file is not know to help with such problems.

Comment: Actually there certainly was a clue statistics would be the problem, which is precisely why I answered the way I did (I've experienced exactly this problem before).

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to drop indexes as well, when you truncated the table and once the data is loaded into the table then go ahead and create the indexes, this will at least solve the issue to some extent.

With the given information I am not sure of what utility you are using to load the rows into the table,

if you are using BCP, then please mention batch size to a appropriate value, as 6 million records going into one single transaction will create a very big transaction, instead of that you can create a batch size of 50,000 and if any batch fails then truncate the whole table before loading again.

For reading more about batch size, please go to through page (the -b option)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx

Comment: Surendra , we are not allowed to create/drop index . rebuild index is done by a schedule task by DBA.

Comment: When you said you insert rows in batches from stored proc, what are you using the simple insert statement or BCP or bulk insert?

Comment: All of this is general advice not addressing the specific problem of his. Also, none of this could explain a performance loss of 20x.